# Calculate vector with given angle and length

Tags: javascript, coordinates, angle

Is there any way in which, in javascript, I can call a function with an x and y co-ord and a direction (angle in degrees) and it will return a set of new co-ords that has been 'moved' by 10px in the direction given from the original co-ords? I looked around but all I can find is ways to get the angle of two given co-ords.

Comment: When you say `Direction`, how do you plan on describing this? For example - you could you an angle (θ) relative to the x axis. The method of describing this is important to your answer. javascript is really irrelevant as the implementation would be the same regardless of the language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This function returns an array `[xCoord, yCoord`] of the new coordinates:

```
function myFunction(xCoord, yCoord, angle, length) {
    length = typeof length !== 'undefined' ? length : 10;
    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180; // if you're using degrees instead of radians
    return [length * Math.cos(angle) + xCoord, length * Math.sin(angle) + yCoord]
}
```

Comment: no point in using `!==` operator, `!=` will do just fine since you know you are comparing it to a string and you know `typeof` returns a string.

Comment: You're right, `!=` will be sufficient, but using the strict equality operators `!==` and `===` is a [recommended best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) as it doesn't encourage type coercion, which is carried out by unmemorable rules.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to point out, that the answers of are not correct IMHO. I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codingfreaks/chfLqrsu/32/) showing that the correct implementation must be something like this:

```js
function getRelativeVector(angle, length, xOffset, yOffset) {
    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180; 
    return { 
        X:length * Math.sin(angle) + xOffset, 
        Y:length * Math.cos(angle) + yOffset 
    };
}
```

The other solutions shown here from @Audrius and @Markus are simply twisted in `cos` and `sin`. They are working for angles between 0 and 45 degrees only.

The formula would be:

- `X = length * sin(angle) + xLocation`
- `Y = length * cos(angle) + yLocation`

Answer (score 0):

The shift in x coordinate is `L*cos(a)` and shift in y coordinate is `L*sin(a)`, where `a` is the angle ("direction given") and `L` is 10 px in your case.

Comment: When I do `10*Math.cos(90)` it returns -4.480736161291702, if 90 degrees is right, shouldn't that just be 10?

Comment: See my response. `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` take angles measured in radians as their arguments, so you'll need to convert degrees into radians (see the comment in my code).

Comment: oh I see, this uses radians instead of degrees, probably should have specified that.